# Problem in saving items pipeline to MySQL DB using scrapy spider

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am trying to save the items from items.py to mysqldb but for some reason It is not getting saved in the database table.
This is how my items.py looks like:

```
import scrapy


class MonitorItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like: 
    id = scrapy.Field()
    company_id = scrapy.Field()
    exchange_id = scrapy.Field()
    doc_name = scrapy.Field()
    doc_link = scrapy.Field()
    publication_date = scrapy.Field()
    update_timestamp = scrapy.Field()
    session_id = scrapy.Field()
    doctype_code = scrapy.Field()
    language_code = scrapy.Field()
```

This is how my pipeline.py looks like:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os, pathlib
import pymysql


class MonitorPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        configs = ConfigParser()
        path = pathlib.Path(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        configs.read(path.parent.parent/'config.ini')
        self.mysql_connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='technophile',
                                           password='tech@nophile343', db='storage')
        self.cursor = self.mysql_connection.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""insert into complete_info(id, company_id, exchange_id, doc_name, doc_link, 
            publication_date, update_timestamp, session_id, doctype_code, language_code) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,
            %s,%s,%s,%s)""",
                                (item['id'], item['company_id'], item['exchange_id'], item['doc_name'], item['doc_link'], item['publication_date'], item['update_timestamp'], item['session_id'], item['doctype_code'], item['language_code']))
            self.mysql_connection.commit()
            print('It is saved!!')
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))

            return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.mysql_connection.close()
```

And this is my settings.py file:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'monitor.pipelines.MonitorPipeline': 300,
}
```

The reason I used a print in `pipeline.py` is because I wanted to check if anything is getting displayed either on terminal or in the logs file, but unfortunately nothing is getting displayed.

Here is the logs.txt

```
2021-09-15 15:42:13 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.0 started (bot: pub_monitor)
2021-09-15 15:42:13 [scrapy] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.8.10 (default, May  5 2021, 03:01:07) - [GCC 7.5.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.27
2021-09-15 15:42:13 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'pub_monitor',
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
 'LOG_FILE': '/mnt/f/Proj111/monitor/logs/logs.txt',
 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
 'LOG_SHORT_NAMES': True,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'monitor.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['monitor.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
               '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'}
2021-09-15 15:42:13 [scrapy] INFO: Telnet Password: htw0mu194i7846nf
2021-09-15 15:42:13 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-09-15 15:42:13 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-09-15 15:42:13 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-09-15 15:42:14 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['monitor.pipelines.MonitorPipeline']
2021-09-15 15:42:14 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2021-09-15 15:42:14 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-09-15 15:42:14 [scrapy] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-09-15 15:42:18 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-09-15 15:42:18 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 948,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 129434,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3.860591,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 15, 10, 12, 18, 596148),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 654303,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 144068608,
 'memusage/startup': 144068608,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 15, 10, 12, 14, 735557)}
2021-09-15 15:42:18 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

How do I possibly ensure that the items are pushed into the database table of MySQL DB? Please help me out!! I am relatively new to webscraping using scrapy framework.

Comment: Where is the spider?

Comment: do you want me to upload the complete code for spider or? @ThiagoCurvelo

Comment: It seems to me that there is some issue with your spider code. It would be helpful if you could share it